# How to repartition equaly by using pyspark sql

Tags: python, pyspark, partition

I have some data with 10000 rows. I want to split it equally not by any columns. It should be like 2000,2000,2000,2000,2000. We should write it as 2000 each.

Tried with  coalesce
And also I have tried partition too. but it's not equally distributed.

```py
final.coalesce(4).write.mode('overwrite').option("header", "true")
```

Comment: I have used repartition and checked ..still we are getting files with different size.. could you please suggest me to get it equally

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use [repartition](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.repartition) instead of coalesce. Coalesce is faster, because it doesn't shuffle, but that can result in not equally distributed partitions, as you noticed.

```py
final = final.repartition(5)
```

should do the job for the numbers you give.

Comment: Ok but in repartition also its not equally distributed